Issue Running Python Application with Bazel - ImportError with NumPy C-Extensions
I have a Python project which I am building and running with Bazel. The project includes dependencies such as flask, transformers, and numpy. When I attempt to run my application using Bazel, I encounter an ImportError related to NumPy's C-extensions:
Error Message:
INFO: Analyzed target //inference:run_app (1 packages loaded, 4 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //inference:run_app up-to-date:
bazel-bin/inference/run_app
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.159s, Critical Path: 0.69s
INFO: 4 processes: 4 internal.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 4 total actions
INFO: Running command line: bazel-bin/inference/run_app
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_modit/96245a706bfbcbe234af177b6d166fc2/execroot/_main/bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/inference/run_app.runfiles/infaas_deps_numpy/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from . import multiarray
File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_modit/96245a706bfbcbe234af177b6d166fc2/execroot/_main/bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/inference/run_app.runfiles/infaas_deps_numpy/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 10, in <module>
from . import overrides
File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_modit/96245a706bfbcbe234af177b6d166fc2/execroot/_main/bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/inference/run_app.runfiles/infaas_deps_numpy/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 8, in <module>
from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

> ...

ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
your python interpreter from there.

Steps to Reproduce

Clone the repository from GitHub.
Run bazel run //inference:run_app.

Observations

The error suggests that NumPy's C-extensions cannot be found.
Running the application directly in a virtual environment created from the requirements.txt file in the inference folder works without any issues.

Build and Run Configuration
WORKSPACE File:
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")


# Update the SHA and VERSION to the lastest version available here:
# https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/releases.

SHA="f4770504f74b9ef87984224a06df35b931d35a2e695ea898102bd9df30ce4fe6"

VERSION="0.32.0"

http_archive(
    name = "rules_python",
    sha256 = SHA,
    strip_prefix = "rules_python-{}".format(VERSION),
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/releases/download/{}/rules_python-{}.tar.gz".format(VERSION,VERSION),
)

load("@rules_python//python:repositories.bzl", "py_repositories")

py_repositories()

load("@rules_python//python:repositories.bzl", "python_register_toolchains")

python_register_toolchains(
    name = "python_3_11",
    # Available versions are listed in @rules_python//python:versions.bzl.
    # We recommend using the same version your team is already standardized on.
    python_version = "3.11",
)

load("@python_3_11//:defs.bzl", interpreter_3_11 = "interpreter")

load("@rules_python//python:pip.bzl", "pip_parse")

# Create a central repo that knows about the dependencies needed from
# requirements_lock.txt.
pip_parse(
   name = "infaas_deps",
   requirements_lock = "//inference:requirements_lock.txt",
   python_interpreter_target = interpreter_3_11,
   download_only = True,
)
# Load the starlark macro, which will define your dependencies.
load("@infaas_deps//:requirements.bzl", "install_deps")
# Call it to define repos for your requirements.
install_deps()


BUILD.bazel
# load("@infaas_deps//:requirements.bzl", "requirement")
load("@infaas_deps//:requirements.bzl", "requirement")


py_library(
    name = "svc",
    deps = [
        requirement("flask"),
        requirement("transformers"),
        requirement("torch"),
    ],
)

py_binary(
    name = "run_app",
    srcs = [
        "app.py",
        ],
    deps = [
        ":svc",
    ],
    main = "app.py",
)

py_binary(
    name = "print_env",
    srcs = ["print_env.py"],
    main = "print_env.py",
    deps = [
        ":svc",
        requirement("setuptools"),  # Ensure setuptools is included for pkg_resources
    ],
)

Additional Information

Python Version: 3.11
NumPy Version: 1.26.4
The error mentions checking the Python and NumPy versions and ensuring they are as expected.

C Libraries and Shared Objects
It appears that the issue may be related to the C libraries and shared objects not being found during runtime. The locations of these libraries and shared objects don't seem to be searched properly.
Question
Why am I encountering this ImportError with NumPy's C-extensions when running the application via Bazel, but not when using a local virtual environment? How can I resolve this issue to successfully run my application using Bazel?

Just tested your repo on my Windows dev box - it just works ;) - should copy and sell my dev box ;) - Bazel on Windows is less restrictive when it comes to hermeticity...

The issue is tied explicitly to enabling bzlmod, which causes workspace toolchains to no longer be registered correctly. This is a known issue tracked in the Bazel rules_python GitHub repository: Issue #1675.
Disabling bzlmod (--noenable_bzlmod) or switching to the bzlmod Python rules resolves the issue.
